Laravel 11 custome authentication with JWT
I have a database from other project which used password_verify() function to hash passwords. So I need to make custome logic to authenticate user and then make JWT token.
But I am little lost in the guards which will use password_verify() and will check the JWT token generated after the login. Is there some example to do it?
